# Tesseract in Xcode C++ project

Tags: c++, c, xcode, image-processing, tesseract

I installed tesseract on my mac and i have the libtesseract.3.dylib and libtesseract.a.I added these files to the C++ command line project and added the header # include or just #include "baseapi.h". It is throwing errors in both the cases. The error is file not found in the former and some other library files are missing in the latter.I added all the header files in the xcode but still it is difficult.Can someone please tell how to include tesseract in Xcode and work with it?

Comment: It's hard to answer without details, how do you installed tesseract (binary or source?). What is the exact command line? Which is the example you are trying? And the exact error that is throwing? It's always better to provide an [mcve].

Comment: Post the *exact* errors. Not your interpretation of them.

Comment: I installed tesseract on my system using macports and i tried the simple terminal command "tesseract imagename outputfile" and it worked fine.Now, i need to perform the same from my project.The project is a command line project using c++ language in Xcode. I am trying to implement the example given in the link below   [link]https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample#compiling-c-api-programs-on-linux

Comment: The error i got is many people said different ways to add the library files to to the project. The simplest one was #include "baseapi.h" but when i include the same, it asks for new file called platform.h.Hence,i downloaded the total project from github and added the platform.h but kept the number of files required kept on increasing. Hence,i wondered similar to opencv,i can add the dylib file which comprises of all files.I found the dylib and added to the project. I referenced the library files using #include <Tesseract\baseapi.h> but it throws an error stating "tesseract\baseapi.h" not found